# Finding specific string in XML file and storing in another file

Tags: filenames, string, search, xml

Text in input file is like this

```
<title>
    <band height="21"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
        <staticText>
            <reportElement
                x="1"
                y="1"
                width="313"
                height="20"
                key="staticText-1"/>
                <box></box>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" size="14" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[4) Computation of Tier I and Tier II Capital :]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</title>
```

Output file should have:

```
4) Computation of Tier I and Tier II Capital :
```

The file has many `<title>` and `[CDATA]` tags. but I want to copy text which is under tag `<title>` under `<CDATA>` and save its output in another file.

Comment: Using what? Bash? Not likely to survive minor formatting changes in the file. SMOP in Python...

Comment: `grep '4) Computation of Tier I and Tier II Capital :' input.txt > output.txt` :/ You'll have to give us more specific details about what strings are allowed, and what are not. Perhaps give us an example of what is not allowed, and a few that are allowed.

Comment: if required string is always within ** then try `cat file | grep -rin \* | cut -d \* -f 3`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may have tried to put a pair of `**` sequences into your `CDATA` section to highlight it here. Unfortunately that has turned it into invalid XML. Assuming you meant this instead,

```
<text><![CDATA[4) Computation of Tier I and Tier II Capital :]]></text>
```

you can use an XML parser to parse your XML:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -v '//text' -n x.xml
4) Computation of Tier I and Tier II Capital :
```

If you have a tighter constraint than just "the contents of the `<text/>` element" you can adjust the XPath filter appropriately. For example:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -v '/title/band/staticText/text' -n x.xml
4) Computation of Tier I and Tier II Capital :
```

Comment: xmlstarlet is now working in my unix machine

Comment: Great stuff. So you're sorted then?

Comment: @AnkitaJain Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$ sed -n '/<title>/,/<\/title>/p' input.txt | grep -oP '(?<=\[CDATA\[).*(?=\])'
```

- `sed` will print everything between the `<title>` and `</title>` (and include this tags). If your `[CDATA` is always just in this area you can omit this step
- `grep` will print out everything what is preceded by `[CDATA[` and followed by `]`

Comment: ** with CDATA is wrongly put. correct line is: [CDATA[4) Computation of Tier I and Tier II Capital :]]

Comment: Then just remove the `**`. I've edited my answer.